# PostgreSQL trigger when syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a trigger but I get a syntax error when I use the WHEN statement like in [the `CREATE TRIGGER` docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

I could of course put the condition in the function but I guess this would be a lot slower and less beautiful

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_test
AFTER INSERT
ON mountain_stats
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
FROM mountain_stats_history
WHERE country=NEW.country AND key=NEW.key AND value=NEW.value))
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_mountain_stats_history();
```

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Error message? (You linked to the 9.1 docs, but that doesn't necessarily mean you're on 9.1).

Answer (score 2):

This won't work since the WHEN condition doesn't support subqueries (see [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) here).

Depending how you write your history update function, it shouldn't be particularly show or inelegant. If you are concerned about a very high volume of writes, there are techniques you might explore to optimize the history update process.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the word when with the word where.

Comment: That is plain wrong. The condition on a trigger **is** defined through the keyword `when`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry I ment WHEN

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was running 9.1 but I am actually only running 8.4 and the WHEN clause is not supported there. 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html
I will need to put the condition in the UDF